# How to ensure all public mirrors contain same content?

Tags: linux, security, storage, static-content

Basically I plan to have some files mirrored on multiple servers on different providers.

A unique cname will auto-balance the traffic across all available mirrors and will serve from the closest to the user. What I am afraid is the following:

What if the hosting sponsor gets hacked or the content hosted gets modified in any way and any reason. How do I prevent that from happening? Is there any way to ensure all servers contain 100% unmodified content?

- Load balancing is DNS based so there is no way to test before sending the user over there.
- There are at least 5000files mirrored across the servers

Comment: If there was a 100% way to prevent hacking, don't you think it'd have been implemented everywhere already?

Comment: I didn't say I want to prevent hacking. I want in case it gets hacked the content wont get served to the users. Since this is not a website and just static files I thought there should be a way to somehow validate the integrity.

Comment: Why not use a CDN and let Amazon, Akamai, etc. handle that security for you?

Comment: Sorry but using a CDN is not applicable. The task is to utilize sponsored servers and hosting and maintain malware free network of content.

Comment: You're talking about _implementing_ a CDN, so at least considering a third party CDN isn't unrealistic.

Comment: A third-party CDN costs money, we have plenty of free sponsored servers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using rsync?  It's used often to push the same files making up e.g. source code repositories to mirror sites.  For example

rsync -rtvuc src_folder/ dst_folder/

Options exist for doing this over ssh, preserving permissions, timestamps etc.  One size doesn't fit all, you'll need to man rsync and experiment.

Comment: You mean just run rsync once in a while and overwrite changed files?

Comment: You didn't specify a platform.  In Unix, a cron job can run periodically and will update only what changed (if anything)